# Is there a way to increase the DevTools timeout for source maps in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Our source maps fail to load. With error: "DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://someurlicantshare.com. Load canceled due to load timeout".

They are definitely available at the URL because I can download it manually if I click on the url in the warning message in the console. It actually just takes a second to download. The source maps are 15MB in size.

I've looked in the DevTools settings but can't find anything. Google searches didn't seem to bring back anything useful.